# partial sum of geometrical sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find partial sum of geometrical sequence with a2=12 and a5=324 
Find 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 4\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{k-1}.$$  Hope fully this makes sense.  I am trying to understand how to do this.  I currently know that the 4 may be a or a1 and the ratio is then 1/2.  Please can someone set me on the right path.  thanks

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Comment: Your first sentence and the second don't seem to have anything to do with each other.  Each is a geometric series, but the second starts with 4 and goes down from there.

Comment: Yes that is indeed how it should look.  The question identifies a12 and a5 and then it give's this symbol with all the things around it.  From the page it looks like one question.  Perhaps it is a typo.  Should I try to tackle it doing 2 different questions?

Answer (score 1):

For your first sentence, if $a_0$ is the first term and the ratio is $r$, you have $a_2=a_0r^2=12$ and $a_5=a_0r^5=324$  Divide these, take a cube root, and you have $r$

For the second do you know how to sum a [geometric series?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Comment: I know I have to add them but it is all new to me

Answer (score 0):

The $n$-term geometric series

$$ a + ar + ar^2 + \dots + ar^{n-1}$$

evaluates to

$$ a\frac{1-r^n}{1-r} = a\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}, $$

provided $r\neq 1$.  (When $r=1$, the $k$-term series $a+\dots+a$ clearly evaluates to $ka$.  Note that $\lim_{r\to 1} \frac{r^k-1}{r-1} = k$, for example by L'Hospital's rule.)

One elementary proof of this is:

$$ \begin{aligned}
  s & = a + ar + ar^2 + \dots + ar^{n-1} \\
  {}-rs & = \phantom{a } - ar - ar^2 - \dots - ar^{n-1} - ar^n \\
  \hline 
  s - rs & = a \phantom{{}+ ar + ar^2 + \dots + ar^{n-1}} - ar^n
\end{aligned} $$
Dividing by $(1-r)$ gives the claim.

Is this what you were asking?

You also ask about an infinite geometric series, which can be evaluated similarly if you know that it converges.  (And does converge iff $|r|<1$, by the above formula.)

Finally, you ask about the geometric series $\sum a_k$ with second summand $a_2 = 12$ and fifth summand $a_5 = 324$.  Note that $\frac{a_5}{a_2} = \frac{324}{12} = 27 = 3^3$, and so $a_1 = 4$, $r = 3$, and $a_k = 4\cdot 3^{k-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have the sum of a geometric series is
$$
\frac{a}{1-r}
$$
where $a$ is the first term of the series and $r$ is the common ration. Then observe
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty 4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) ^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-3}
$$
So the first term is when $k=1$, so $a=4$ and the common ratio is $r=1/2$. This yields sum
$$
\frac{a}{1-r}=\frac{4}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=8
$$